# How to get the values by the index Lua

Tags: lua

Hello there I'm new in Lua and a have a question, I have this code:

```
dialogExample = "1. han3x1 2. 1kekeo 3. 103kdo 4. 54o4as 5. asbf1c 6. ask6os"

for k in string.gmatch(dialogExample, "[^%s]+") do
    print(k)
end

output:

1. 
han3x1
2.
1kekeo
3.
103kdo
4.
54o4as
5.
asbf1c
6. 
ask6os
```

How can I get the the values by the index, for exemple, I just want to print the value of the line 1. in  this case "han3x1", How can I do this?

I want get just the "1. han3x1", after I just want the value "4. 54o4as". But these values are random

I appreciate any help, thank's

Comment: I don't fully understand the question here. Do you need to use the string matching or can you store the values in a table directly? (and in that way you automatically have an index reference to your values)

Comment: Actually these values are random, but I need to get them separate, there's any way to get them by the number of the index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

perhaps your case describes a pattern like this:

```
local dialogExample = "1. han3x1 2. 1kekeo 3. 103kdo 4. 54o4as 5. asbf1c 6. ask6os"
local t = {}
for i,v in string.gmatch(dialogExample, "(%d+)[%.%s]*([^%s]+)") do
    t[i] = v
    print(i,t[i])
end
```

out:

```
1    han3x1
2    1kekeo
3    103kdo
4    54o4as
5    asbf1c
6    ask6os
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a table

```
-- table with index keys from 1 to 6
dialogExample = {"han3x1", "1kekeo", "103kdo", "54o4as", "asbf1c", "ask6os"}

for i = 1, #dialogExample do
    io.write(('%d.\n%s\n'):format(i, dialogExample[i]))
end
```

Output:

```
1. 
han3x1
2.
1kekeo
3.
103kdo
4.
54o4as
5.
asbf1c
6. 
ask6os
```

Than...

```
io.write(('%d.\n%s\n'):format(1, dialogExample[1]))
```

Output:

```
1.
han3x1
```

Comment: Thank's for the help. But the problem, it's when I receive the values, they come like this: "1. han3x1 2. 1kekeo 3. 103kdo 4. 54o4as 5. asbf1c 6. ask6os", in just one string, I don't know how to separate them like a table

Comment: OK - Than also take a look at the gsub() method. It is a magic wand for strings. gsub can handle the pattern match with string/table/function and knows a count parameter. Example with a function: ```do dialogExample:gsub('^%d%.%s%g+', function(...) print(...) return end, 1) end``` - Gives out only the first match with a count of 1.

Comment: Solved, thank's for the help, I appreciate